# Jquery dotdotdot.js plugin not functioning properly for text with html elements

Tags: jquery, html, ellipsis, dotdotdot

I am using dotdotdot.js for my project.
Recently, I added a rich-text editor (tinymce), and the text now has some html elements like p,a,b,i, etc.
dotdotdot is not working as expected for this text.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dgkdN/

```
$(".text-ellipsis").dotdotdot({
    watch: "true", 
    after: ".read-more", 
    callback: function (isTruncated, orgContent) {
        if (isTruncated) {
            $('.read-more', this).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Please find the screenshot showing the problem below:
[image]

The "Useruuu" text should show up fully. But it is cut off to half its vertical height. That is the problem that I am facing.
I want to show it normally, I mean, full height of the line. Or show only "..." if it cant take up the available vertical height

Please help!

Comment: Seems to work for me, but you haven't really said what your expectation is

Comment: @jumpingcode: Added the screenshot in the question. Pls check

Comment: That's the result, not the expectation.

Comment: The "Useruuu" text should show up fully. But it is cut off to half its vertical height. That is the problem that I am facing. I want to show it normally, I mean, full height of the line. Or atleast show "..." if it cant take up the available vertical height

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake in framing the question. Hope I clarified it

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow: hidden` from your fiddle:

```
.text-ellipsis{ max-height:27px; width:100%; }
```

***[SEE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dgkdN/1/)***

Comment: But there is no "..." after "Useruuu" to show that the text is truncated

Comment: @EvilDevil `dotdotdot` only truncates text wrapped in a `.text-ellipsis` class. Your first class of this type has enclosing HTML elements, i.e. `<p>`

Answer (score 0):

The `p` is a block element with a default padding. You can either remove/replace this padding

```
.dotdotdot p {
     padding:0;
    }
```

or you can set the `p` (and other block elements placed by rich text editor, too) to `inline`.

```
.dotdotdot > * {
  display: inline;
}
```